# How to print radio buttons in table using loop

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am trying to print the radio buttons in table. I am using php and i am printing the radio button using the loop.

But when i run the browser with this page, it is not showing the radio button.

code:

```
echo "<form>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>da</th></tr>";

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Bad escaping.You will get syntax error.

Comment: @User016 I didn't get it...!

Comment: If you run the code you will understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your radio buttons aren't printing is due to the nature of Echo and the " character.

Looking at the broken line

```
echo "<td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /></td>";
```

If you see how you've used echo "

Echo wants a string to print, so it looks for something in between either " or '.

your current code means that it will try to print

```
"<td><input type="
```

then it gets a bit confused because the word radio is written in the code, this will make php freak out and crash.

Not to worry, you can just alternate between ' and " to do html attributes, like so

```
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /></td>";
```

should be

```
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='q1' value='5' /></td>";
```

or escape the `"` with `\"` like this:

```
echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1\" value=\"5\" /></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /></td>';
```

instead of

```
echo "<td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo '<form><table border='1'><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>da</th></tr>';
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /></td>
</tr>';
}
echo '</table>
</form>';
?>
```